# Correct format of mongo return document on updateOne using mongo node driver

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Looking at the [current mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/), I get the following explanation on mongo updateOne return:

> Returns The method returns a document that contains:
>
> matchedCount containing the number of matched documents modifiedCount
>   containing the number of modified documents upsertedId containing the
>   _id for the upserted document. A boolean acknowledged as true if the operation ran with write concern or false if write concern was
>   disabled

I'm calling a simple updateOne from my javascript code using the mongo node driver and getting the following document as a result:

```
let result = db.updateOne({ userName: "John" }, { $set: { age: 30 }}, { upsert: true});

CommandResult {
  result: { n: 1, nModified: 0, upserted: [ [Object] ], ok: 1 },
  connection: Connection {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      commandStarted: [Function],
      commandFailed: [Function],
      commandSucceeded: [Function],
      clusterTimeReceived: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    id: 1,
    address: '127.0.0.1:27017',
    bson: BSON {},
    socketTimeout: 360000,
    monitorCommands: false,
    closed: false,
    destroyed: false,
    lastIsMasterMS: 25,
    [Symbol(description)]: StreamDescription {
      address: '127.0.0.1:27017',
      type: 'Standalone',
      minWireVersion: 0,
      maxWireVersion: 8,
      maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216,
      maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000,
      maxWriteBatchSize: 100000,
      compressors: []
    },
    [Symbol(generation)]: 0,
    [Symbol(lastUseTime)]: 1590008021689,
    [Symbol(queue)]: Map {},
    [Symbol(messageStream)]: MessageStream {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      bson: BSON {},
      maxBsonMessageSize: 67108864,
      [Symbol(buffer)]: [BufferList]
    },
    [Symbol(stream)]: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'localhost',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      timeout: 360000,
      _peername: [Object],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 32,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 360000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [Timeout],
        _idleStart: 50804,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 42,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 32
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    [Symbol(ismaster)]: {
      ismaster: true,
      maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216,
      maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000,
      maxWriteBatchSize: 100000,
      localTime: 2020-05-20T20:52:52.930Z,
      logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30,
      connectionId: 488,
      minWireVersion: 0,
      maxWireVersion: 8,
      readOnly: false,
      ok: 1
    }
  },
  message: BinMsg {
    parsed: true,
    raw: <Buffer 6f 00 00 00 42 1f 03 00 26 00 00 00 dd 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5a 00 00 00 10 6e 00 01 00 00 00 10 6e 4d 6f 64 69 66 69 65 64 00 00 00 00 00 04 75 70 ... 61 more bytes>,
    data: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 5a 00 00 00 10 6e 00 01 00 00 00 10 6e 4d 6f 64 69 66 69 65 64 00 00 00 00 00 04 75 70 73 65 72 74 65 64 00 29 00 00 00 03 30 00 21 00 ... 45 more bytes>,
    bson: BSON {},
    opts: { promoteLongs: true, promoteValues: true, promoteBuffers: false },
    length: 111,
    requestId: 204610,
    responseTo: 38,
    opCode: 2013,
    fromCompressed: undefined,
    responseFlags: 0,
    checksumPresent: false,
    moreToCome: false,
    exhaustAllowed: false,
    promoteLongs: true,
    promoteValues: true,
    promoteBuffers: false,
    documents: [ [Object] ],
    index: 95
  },
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: { index: 0, _id: 5ec598d5c1eaed085d51cbe6 },
  upsertedCount: 1,
  matchedCount: 0
}
```

Am I missing something? How can I get a success return from the call (I wish to know if the command succeedeed or failed) ?

Comment: What do you expect it to return? The updated document? Because the result already included the fields you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You referred to the mongo shell method reference.

If you are using the node.js native driver, you can find the API Reference [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/)

The return [result properties](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#~updateWriteOpResult) of [`updateOne`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#updateOne) matches with what you got.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using findOneAndUpdate setting *returnNewDocument* option to `true`

```
let result = db.findOneAndUpdate({ userName: "John" }, { $set: { age: 30 }}, { upsert: true, returnNewDocument : true})
```

If you use mongoose:
replace `returnNewDocument` with `new`